# How to save .jpeg/.tiff image into device gallery in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, image, gallery

I want to save my .jpeg and .tiff image with custom album into the gallery of device.

So I have refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27660747/3908884) for saving an image with custom album into  the gallery.

```
let myImage = UIImage.init(named: "image.tiff")
self.createAlbum(myImage!) //This method is taken from above linked answer
```

But it saves image into .jpg format always.

Also I am trying to save image with default album using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29502530/3908884). But it also saves image into .jpg format.

I have read several posts here about saving image into gallery. Unfortunately, it seems that there is not any "good" solution.

When I saved my image into the document directory. It saved with right format. But When I am trying to save this image into device gallery, then it always saves into .jpg format.

**Is there any other way to save image with custom name into the custom album in gallery..?**

I want to save my .jpeg image and .tiff image into gallery of device.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can Save Image using following code

```
import AssetsLibrary


let image = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)  
//or let image = UIImage.init(named: "image.tiff")

ALAssetsLibrary().writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, metadata: nil, completionBlock: { (assetURL: NSURL!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        print(assetURL)
})
```

But apple stores it by default JPG Format.
You are not able to change it. It Totally managed by Apple.

Comment: For iOS9, `ALAssetsLibrary` is deprecated. That's why I am using `PHPhotoLibrary`.

Comment: Are you sure, Apple can't allow this things.? have you any doc or link regarding this.?